# systemd service for a perlbrew application?

Tags: perl, systemd, dancer, perlbrew

My coworker wrote a Dancer psgi application called "Newlands" that makes use of perlbrew. I am trying to get the application to start up on system start using systemd. I have this service file:

```
[Unit]
Description=Newlands
After=network-online.target

[Service]
Type=forking
User=newlands
WorkingDirectory=/home/newlands/working/newlands
PIDFile=/home/newlands/newlands.pid
ExecStartPre=/bin/bash -c 'env > /tmp/newlands.environment'
ExecStartPre=/bin/mkdir -p /tmp/newlands/newlands/session/
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/starman --host 127.0.0.1 --listen :5000 --env production --preload-app --workers 12 --daemonize --error-log /var/log/newlands/newlands.error.log --pid /home/newlands/newlands.pid bin/newlandia.psgi
EnvironmentFile=-/tmp/newlands.environment
Restart=always

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

However, even with the ExecStartPre trick (which I got from http://tech.akom.net/archives/93-Getting-a-systemd-unit-to-read-your-.bashrc-file-for-its-environment.html, modified not use the --login option), none of the perlbrew-related environment variables are getting set properly. So I end up with errors indicating missing libraries not found in @INC, when @INC doesn't contain anything at /home/newlands/.perlbrew/libs/perl-5.20.1@newlands where the libraries actually are.

It seems that the outputted file at /tmp/newlands.environment still differs significantly from the output of "env" when actually logged in as the newlands user. I would like to source /opt/perlbrew/etc/bashrc or something like that, but I understand that's not possible.

Any tips? Thanks!

Comment: Re "*none of the perlbrew-related environment variables are getting set properly*", `perlbrew` servers two purposes, 1) a wrapper for a `perl` installer, and 2) a PATH manipulation tool. Neither of these should be relevant here.

Comment: Re "*So I end up with errors indicating missing libraries not found in @INC, when @INC doesn't contain anything at `/home/newlands/.perlbrew/libs/perl-5.20.1@newlands` where the libraries actually are.*", uh, that's not where `perlbrew`-installed `perl` builds install libs. You seem to have overridden the install location? If so, you'll use `use lib ...` inside of your script, or set the `PERL5LIB` env var. (Neither of those things have anything to do with `perlbrew`. In fact, `perlbrew` is usually used to *avoid* doing these things!)

Comment: Actually, what you're trying to do works, but only if you split it into two services. The reason for this is that `EnvironmentFile` seems to be read _before_ `ExecStartPre` commands are executed. So if you create another `Type=oneshot` service called `myapp_env.service` that generates your environment file and in your `myapp.service` add `Requires=app_env.service` and `After=app_env.service` in the `Unit` section you should be good to go. In case of a perlbrew application that would be to `source $PERLBREW_ROOT/etc/bashrc` and then pipe the output of `printenv` to generate your file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution is not to blindly dump your Bash CLI environment into your systemd environment, the solution is to understand what environment variables you need and set those.

As @ikegami points out, your problem is likely related to the `PERL5LIB` environment variable. So run your app from the CLI from and dump out the value of `$ENV{PERL5LIB}` to see what value the app expects, then set that in `systemd`. You may need to repeat the process with other variables.

The result will be a clearly and precisely defined `systemd` environment that will run your app in a stable and consistent manner, regardless of how your `.bashrc` gets modified.